# Overwriting HTTP response headers

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to overwrite the http response headers returned in Jmeter? I'm testing a web service that returns JSON and when an invalid request is sent, the JSON response returned doesn't contain application/json (or any for that matter) in the response header. If I save the response to a file, I see the actual JSON returned, but looking at the response in a Results tree doesn't show a response. Unless there is a way to load the response from file and parse the error message from the file, I'm hoping to somehow overwrite the HTTP response header and force jmeter to treat the response as JSON.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: More details - the failing response is actually of type java.lang.String, and contains what appears to be JSON. Is there a way to parse/assert a returned java.lang.String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out JMeter does not support response header overloading. While the response isn't displayed in the Results tree, it is actually available to other assertions. I was able to still provide assertions to validate responses even though the response was missing from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Using a beanshell post processor, you can write some script that would force the value for the header, or write out to a file.

You can also add a listener that would write the results to file for you. Granted - this is less convenient for debugging then Tree View.